# TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars while plotting the integral of a complex function

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I'm trying to plot the integral of a complex function with this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp


# Integrable function
def complex_function(f):
    return np.exp(2*np.pi*1j*f*t) * (1/np.tan(f/fs - 1j*(a/(2*np.pi*fs))))/(2*np.pi*1j*fs)

def w(t):
    return sp.integrate.quad(lambda f : complex_function(f), -B/2, B/2)[0]

# Variables
B = 1
fs = 1
t = np.linspace(-25, 25, int(50/fs))
a = 1

# Plot
plt.plot(t, w(t), 'b')
plt.show()
```

And this error appears:

```
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

How can I solve it?

I've tried changing the `w(t)` function of place, and working with `arange` instead of `linspace`. However the same error appears.

Comment: where's the error?  FULL error message. You can't 'solve' it without first clearly identifying what it us.

Comment: Your use the `t` array is awkward. Passing it as arg to `w` doesn't do anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

The function `func` that you pass to the function `sp.integrate.quad(func, a, b)` has to return a real value. In your case, `complex_function` is  calculating the complex numbers for all values of `t` at once and returning a vector/tensor/array. To solve the error, you need to call the function `complex_function` for each value of `t` such that the function `complex_function` always return a real/scaler value. Again, in order to call `complex_function` for a value of `t`, you need to pass the value of `t` to the function `complex_function`. I have coded up one of the ways of doing this as shown below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp


# Integrable function
complex_function = lambda f, t: np.exp(2*np.pi*1j*f*t) * (1/np.tan(f/fs - 1j*(a/(2*np.pi*fs))))/(2*np.pi*1j*fs);

def w(t):
  integral_val = [];
  for t_val in t:
    integral_val.append(sp.integrate.quad(complex_function, -B/2, B/2, args=(t_val,)))
  return integral_val

# Variables
B = 1
fs = 1
t = np.linspace(-25, 25, int(50/fs))
a = 1

# Plot
plt.plot(t, w(t), 'b')
plt.show()
```

It plots the integral of the function `complex_function`.

Comment: If this is not what you are expecting, kindly let me know so I can know it and fix it.